# Find a bipartition $V(G)=S\cup T$ such that $\chi(G[S])+\chi(G[T])=\chi(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

As in the title, for every graph $G$, we want to find a bipartition $V(G)=S\cup T$ such that 
$$\chi(G[S])+\chi(G[T])=\chi(G). $$

My attempt is to find a set $S\subseteq V(G)$ of vertices such that each vertex of $S$ is adjacent to all the vertices in $T=V(G)\setminus S$. This will naturally give the equality we want.

But the main problem is how we can find out such subset $S$. Is there any good algorithm for this? Or am I approaching this problem in a wrong way? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show how to compute $\chi(G)$ for a general graph using this algorithm.

Given a graph $G$ we w

---

If there were a polynomial algorithm, with

> **Input**: undirected simple graph $G=(V,E)$
>
> **Outuput**: partition of the graph to two (disjoint) sets of vertices $S,T$ such that $\chi(G[S])+\chi(G[T])=\chi(G)$

Then one could use it to find $\chi(G)$ of any graph.

### Polynomial reduction from exact-coloring problem to the stated problem:

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, we can use the algorithm recursively to find what is $\chi(G)$.
The complexity of this algorithm is:
$$T(n)=T(k)+T(n-k) + poly(n)$$
where $1\leq k\leq n$.
By assuming $T(1)=O(1)$ we get:
$$ T(n)=poly(n)$$

Think on the recursion $T(n)=T(k)+T(n-k) + poly(n)$ as a binary tree, where every non-leaf vertex has two children.
We pay at most $poly(n)$ on every such non-leaf vertex.
The question is then reduced to what is the maximal number of vertices in a tree with $n$ leaves where every non-leaf vertex has two children.

one can show by induction the answer is $2n-1$. Therefore, the overall running time is $poly(n)$.

---

Since this is an $\text{NP-Complete}$ problem [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity), we do not know if such an algorithm exists, although it is widely assumed there is no polynomial algorithm to solve this problem.

---

As for an actual answer to your question, a brute force approach - in which you go through all of the options, will turn out to be not "so bad", compared to others, in the general case.

Comment: Awesome! Though I learned the course of computational complexity, I have never turned to this direction before. I just thought this problem is simply a deterministic problem as others, but it turned out to be NP-complete eventually. Thanks a lot for your answer. Again, that is awesome :)